# Disabling 'go' button form submission in Android when using webview

Tags: android, keyboard, webview

I'm developing an Android application and I use a WebView to embed forms into my application. My problem is that android has a soft keyboard and when the user presses 'go' on this keyboard it submits the form. How can I prevent this from happening? I did a power search on google but I did not find any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok in the meantime i got a very simple solution:
In the manifest XML:

```
<activity android:name="..."
...
android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
...
</activity>
```

This way the 'go' button got replaced by 'done' and it hides the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) class and register it with your WebView.

This post discusses this: [Android - how to intercept a form POST in android WebViewClient on API level 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664440/android-how-to-intercept-a-form-post-in-android-webviewclient-on-api-level-4)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. By the way I already got my own client running. :)