# Android: How to pass data from android native code to jquerymobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

My android app is getting session id as part of login service response, for the subsequent requests i have to pass this sess id.
Now I'm using jquerymobile pages as webview content. I have to call some services from jquerymobile page using ajax.

Can I pass sessid from android native code to jquerymobile for this.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Venkat Papana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It's quite the same question I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553455/local-android-service-receive-data-from-local-web-page/7553718#7553718).)
So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664440/android-how-to-intercept-a-form-post-in-android-webviewclient-on-api-level-4/3922941#3922941) describes how to communicate with your webview with a javascript bridge.

I think that's what your looking for...

Comment: Thank you very much @Knickedi, but is it safe to pass sessid from JavaScriptInterface to jQM using a getter method?

Comment: Those pages are local, so on your device? Am I right? It wouldn't be save to communicate with a website you actually not host yourself because you would grant the website to call native code in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you're using ajax, meaning the webview content is served by a remote site.

Assuming you have access to the site javascript, simply define a callback, say `sessidFromAndroid(sessid)` then get it called by java :

```
mWebview.loadUrl("javascript:sessidFromAndroid("+mSession+")");
```