# Send Post request along with HttpHeaders on Android

Tags: android, post, webview, http-headers, android-webview

I need to post data to server (with "referer" header field) and load the response in Webview.

Now, there are different methods (from [Android WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)) to do parts of it, like there is:

```
void loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)
```

Loads the given URL with the specified additional HTTP headers.

```
void loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding)
```

Loads the given data into this WebView using a 'data' scheme URL.

```
void postUrl(String url, byte[] postData)
```

Loads the URL with postData using "POST" method into this WebView.

loadUrl() allows to send HttpHeaders but doesn't allow to send post data, other methods seem to be not allowing to send HttpHeaders. Am I missing something or what I am trying is not possible?

Comment: anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: any one here who can help with this issue?

Comment: I also have the same problem. please anyone has any link to help me

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the `HttpPost` manually like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/postreceiver");

// generating your data (AKA parameters)
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ParameterName", "ParameterValue"));
// ...

// adding your headers
httppost.setHeader("HeaderName", "HeaderValue");
// ...

// adding your data
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Get the `response` as `String`:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    builder.append(line).append("\n");
}
String html = builder.toString();
```

Now you can put the `html` into `yourWebView` by using `loadData()`:

```
yourWebView.loadData(html ,"text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom class that inherits from WebView, or if you prefer, you can add an extension function. The logic is essentially the same:

```kotlin
private fun WebView.postUrl(postUrl: String, postData: ByteArray, additionalHttpHeaders: MutableMap<String, String>) {

    val savedWebViewClient = getWebViewClient()

    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView, url: String): WebResourceResponse? {

            if (url != postUrl) {
                view.post {
                    webViewClient = savedWebViewClient
                }
                return savedWebViewClient?.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url)
            }

            Log.d("WebView extension", "post ${postData.decodeToString()} to ${url}")
            val httpsUrl = URL(url)
            val conn: HttpsURLConnection = httpsUrl.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
            conn.requestMethod = "POST"
            additionalHttpHeaders.forEach { header ->
                conn.addRequestProperty(header.key, header.value)
            }

            conn.outputStream.write(postData)
            conn.outputStream.close()

            val responseCode = conn.responseCode
            Log.d("WebView extension", "responseCode = ${responseCode} ${conn.contentType}")
            view.post {
                webViewClient = savedWebViewClient
            }

            // typical conn.contentType is "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            return WebResourceResponse(conn.contentType.substringBefore(";"), "utf-8", conn.inputStream)
        }
    }

    loadUrl(postUrl, additionalHttpHeaders)
}
```

The code above was redacted for brevity, with most error checking hidden. To work for API below level 26, I use reflection to extract the `savedWebViewClient`.

In real life, you also want to override the new `shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest)` method, and delegate all other methods of your **WebViewClient** to the `savedWebViewClient`. Probably a **PostWithHeadersWebView** class (which overrides also `setWibViewClient()`) could make your life easier.

Comment: conn.outputStream.write(postData) getting an exception in this line.

Comment: @SakhawatHossain which exception? As I mentioned, the code above was stripped all error handling, because I wanted to show the logical flow.