# How to add authorization bearer header to webview android?

Tags: android, kotlin, http-headers, android-webview

I have to send bearer at headers. I saw that I have to add hashMap with values:

```
val headerMap = HashMap<String, String>()
headerMap["Authorization: Bearer "] = context!!.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!
```

and then send data with url:

```
webView.loadUrl(link, headerMap)
```

but as a result I see that I send the wrong format of this token:

```
authorization=bearer :token
```

How I can fix it because with that token I can't get data from page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try to do it this way

```
val bearer = "Bearer " + context!!.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!

val headerMap = HashMap<String,String>()
headerMap["Authorization"] = bearer
webView.loadUrl(link, headerMap)
```

You need to think, you are using a `HashMap` so, means it has a `Key` and a `Value`, `Key` is the [`Header name`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6PEW_9.4.0/com.ibm.help.custom.restapis.doc/c_SpecifyingHTTPHeaders.html) and then the `Value` is the value of that `Header name` so in this case is :

Header name --> `Authorization`

Header value --> `Bearer <your_access_token>`

Comment: it didn't help me :( I sent  -  authorization=Bearer token, but I have to send Authorization: Bearer token

Comment: Can you verify that your data from `SharedPreferences` is working ok?

Comment: I recommend you to check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440736/send-authorization-header-with-every-request-in-webview-using-okhttp-in-android/41442806

Comment: my data from `SharedPreferences` is working ok, and I don't receive any errors in log cat, I also saw this question, but I think that maybe I can reach appropriate result with current solution?

Comment: Also you tried to print headerMap and you realized that the output is in lowercase and not getting the accessToken correctly?

Comment: here is my output of headermap - Authorization=Bearer token, I have to add two dots and remove equality, and also at web view I think I will receive all at lowercase and I don't understand why ;(

Comment: Can you please provide how do you see this text? And the changes you did into your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195497/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-skizo-oziks).