# How do I  know the loaded URL has method type POST in Android?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in Android app and load my webapplication. I am listening the page navigation using ShouldOverrideURL method and do some operation. I want to do specific operation when the URL method type is GET or POST. I cannot use PostURL method here as I load only one home URL.

Comment: Mind rephrasing your question so it'd be less chaotic and more understandable?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like shouldOverrideUrl is only called during GET requests: [Android - how to intercept a form POST in android WebViewClient on API level 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664440/android-how-to-intercept-a-form-post-in-android-webviewclient-on-api-level-4)

If you want to do a specific operation during a POST operation for a particular URL, you want to extend WebView and override `WebView#postUrl(String url, byte[] postData)`.