# Intercept POST requests in a WebView

Tags: android, post, webview, request

I'm developping an Android application filtering the requests (with a white list) and using a custom `SSLSocketFactory`. For this, I've developed a custom `WebViewClient` and I have overridden the `shouldInterceptRequest` method. I can filter and use my `SocketFactory` with the GET requests but I can't intercept the POST requests.

So, is there a way to intercept the POST requests in a `WebView` ?

Here is the code of the shouldInterceptRequest method :

```
public final WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String urlStr) {
    URI uri = URI.create(urlStr);
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    // If scheme not http(s), let the default webview manage it
    if(!"http".equals(scheme) && !"https".equals(scheme)) {
        return null;
    }
    URL url = uri.toURL();

    if(doCancelRequest(url)) {
        // Empty response
        Log.d(TAG, "URL filtered: " + url);
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", new EmptyInputStream());

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "URL: " + url);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", mSettings.getUserAgentString());

        // Configure connections
        configureConnection(conn);

        String mimeType = conn.getContentType();
        String encoding = conn.getContentEncoding();

        if(mimeType != null && mimeType.contains(CONTENT_TYPE_SPLIT)) {
            String[] split = mimeType.split(CONTENT_TYPE_SPLIT);
            mimeType = split[0];

            Matcher matcher = CONTENT_TYPE_PATTERN.matcher(split[1]);
            if(matcher.find()) {
                encoding = matcher.group(1);
            }
        }

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, is);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error, or does it simply not work? You should post some relevant code, such as your overridden `shouldInterceptRequest` method, as well.

Comment: No I have no error. I am logging the url at the start of the shouldInterceptRequest method and I only see the GET requests. The others seems managed in the WebView low level.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue a few days ago.

So I built a library that solves it:

https://github.com/KonstantinSchubert/request_data_webviewclient

It is a WebViewClient with a custom WebResourceRequest that contains the POST/PUT/... payload of XMLHttpRequest requests.

It only works for these though - not for forms and other kind of request sources.

The hack works, basically,  by injecting a script into the HTML that intercepts XMLHttpRequest calls. It records the post/put/... content and sends it to an `android.webkit.JavascriptInterface`. There, the request is stashed until the `shouldInterceptRequest` method is called by Android ...

Comment: Very smart hack for this issue. Thanks. Converted to work with Xamarin.Android and saved the day when facing this problem.

Comment: Great idea, I took the liberty of creating an updated and extended version of your library: https://github.com/acsbendi/Android-Request-Inspector-WebView. I've added support for the missing parts, like forms and fetch requests, as well as recording the exact headers.

Comment: @EmmanuelVazquez : Can you please share the Xamarin.Android version of code to save my day as well :)

Answer (score 3):

I have created a [library](https://github.com/acsbendi/Android-Request-Inspector-WebView) that aims to capture all data of all HTTP requests sent from Android WebViews.

Using this library, you can easily implement sending `POST`, or any other requests. Here's your code adapted to work with the library:

```java
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public final WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebViewRequest request) {
        URI uri = URI.create(request.getUrl());
        String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        // If scheme not http(s), let the default webview manage it
        if(!"http".equals(scheme) && !"https".equals(scheme)) {
            return null;
        }
        URL url = uri.toURL();

        if(doCancelRequest(url)) {
            // Empty response
            Log.d(TAG, "URL filtered: " + url);
            return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", new EmptyInputStream());

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "URL: " + url);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Set request method
            conn.setRequestMethod(request.getMethod());
            // Set request headers
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : request.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
                conn.setRequestProperty(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
            }

            // Set request body, if it's present
            if (!request.getBody().isEmpty()) {
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                osw.write(request.getBody());
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
                os.close();  //don't forget to close the OutputStream
            }
            conn.connect();

            String mimeType = conn.getContentType();
            String encoding = conn.getContentEncoding();

            if(mimeType != null && mimeType.contains(CONTENT_TYPE_SPLIT)) {
                String[] split = mimeType.split(CONTENT_TYPE_SPLIT);
                mimeType = split[0];

                Matcher matcher = CONTENT_TYPE_PATTERN.matcher(split[1]);
                if(matcher.find()) {
                    encoding = matcher.group(1);
                }
            }

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, is);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where this method come from? `request.getBody()`

Comment: It comes from my library, you can find it here: https://github.com/acsbendi/Android-Request-Inspector-WebView

Comment: Good repo! Keep improving it.

Answer (score 0):

I have one of my answers on above thread  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9122

Please see [comment#31](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9122#c31)

Some of the caveats of my solution I see are:

1. Putting a dependency on xmlhttprequest prototype which has different implementation for different webkits.
2. Security issue in sending data for post requests in URL. But I guess you can solve that through some encryption mechanism.
3. URL length issue for some of the browsers if you big data to post

Apart from that, I found [this github repo](https://github.com/KeejOow/android-post-webview) which seems to be solving this problem in another hacky way. I looked into the code but didn't get time to implement and test it. But worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to do this is to just use the [JQuery Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) with a Javascript Interface.

You have to setup the Javascript Interface, but once you do just have it match the signature of the handler you're interested in.

To get the payload, just find the payload variable name put it in the interface.

Here's the Javascript:

```
 $( document ).ajaxSend(function( event, request, settings ) {
      var eventJSON= JSON.stringify(event);
      var requestJSON = JSON.stringify(request);
      var settingsJSON = JSON.stringify(settings);
      var payloadJSON = JSON.stringify(payload);

      myJSInterface.passData(eventJSON,requestJSON,settingsJSON,payloadJSON);       
 });
```

Here's the Kotlin class

```
 class yourJSInterface() {
      lateinit var event: String
      lateinit var request: String
      lateinit var settings: String
      lateinit var payload: String
 
      @JavascriptInterface
      fun passData(eventJSON:String, responseJSON:String, settingsJSON:String,payloadJSON:String){
           event = eventJSON
           response= responseJSON
           settings= settingsJSON
           payload= payloadJSON
      }
 }
```

The registration in the onPageStarted override for WebViewClient

```
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(yourJSInterface,"myJSInterface")
```

Finally the JS injection into the WebView in the OnPageFinished override

```
 webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:" + getString(R.string.js_from_above),null)
```

I registered the interface in onPageStarted because otherwise, the javascript file in onPageFinished won't recognize your interface.

Answer (score -1):

you can get input value before submit

https://github.com/henrychuangtw/WebView-Javascript-Inject

Step 1 : create a class which called by javascript

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
        //called by javascript
    }
}
```

Step 2 : register interface for javascript

```
webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview1.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "MYOBJECT");
```

Step 3 : inject javascript to page

```
webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = function () {");
        sb.append("var objPWD, objAccount;var str = '';");
        sb.append("var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');");
        sb.append("for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {");
        sb.append("if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() === 'password') {objPWD = inputs[i];}");
        sb.append("else if (inputs[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'email') {objAccount = inputs[i];}");
        sb.append("}");
        sb.append("if (objAccount != null) {str += objAccount.value;}");
        sb.append("if (objPWD != null) { str += ' , ' + objPWD.value;}");
        sb.append("window.MYOBJECT.processHTML(str);");
        sb.append("return true;");
        sb.append("};");

        view.loadUrl("javascript:" + sb.toString());
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a simpler solution: send the parameters by GET in the ajax call and transform them to POST in shouldInterceptRequest

Answer (score -4):

Use GET instead of POST.

Known issue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9122

Was answered here as well:
[Android - how to intercept a form POST in android WebViewClient on API level 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664440/android-how-to-intercept-a-form-post-in-android-webviewclient-on-api-level-4)

Comment: Yes, I have found the issue in the android bugtracker. But in my case I can't change the POST into GET request because I don't know what server I will connect to.
For instance, I can't connect to GMail because there is a POST request during the authentication.

Comment: Have a look at this library: https://github.com/KonstantinSchubert/request_data_webviewclient  I wrote it when I was facing a similar problem.