# Get data from Website to android app through WebView

Tags: android, webview

I need to load a website in the WebView, placed inside an activity. The user should see this website through WebView, then fill a form in the website.

If he fills it correctly the app should get a success flag from the website and show another activity. Otherwise, if the user don't fill the form or fill it incorrectly the page should inform the android app.

How could I get data from website through webview?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954049/intercept-post-requests-in-a-webview

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to get data from the website.. When the form is filled correctly a website loads another url.. Mostly to show "you've successfully filled your form" or something similar.. Check if a url different from that of the form starts loading in webView and if it is then Start the other activity.. 
I don't think u need code for this but if you do let me know :)