# Android WebViewClient: How To Get POST request body

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a requirement to get the request body from a POST request in our `WebView`. It doesn't look like the `WebResourceResponse` in `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest` has a method for this. Has anyone had the same issue and how did you worked around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it an external page or your own page which you can modify?

Comment: @greenapps it is an external page.

Comment: Then i do not know a solution.

Comment: are u able to resolve this issue?

Comment: i also need to fetch webview post body from webview

Comment: @NiravBhandari no, we tagged this as a technical limitation for now.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. we also did the same thing.. Finally we are receiving parameter using GET Method via url query string

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: Have the same issue - writing custom browser, loading WebResourceResponse on my own, and can not get body for auth on sites, for example. I am digging on this question more than a week, tell please, do you have any updates on this?

Comment: Looks like this is still open, you can check (and follow up) in the Android issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37014582

Comment: still no solution?

Comment: @AntonKizema did you find anything to solve this?

Comment: up until now looks like its still an existing issue

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [library](https://github.com/acsbendi/Android-Request-Inspector-WebView) that aims to capture all data of all HTTP requests sent from Android WebViews, including the request body.

Using this library, you can easily read the request body like this:

```kotlin
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView,
        webViewRequest: WebViewRequest
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        Log.i("RequestInspectorWebView", "Here's the body: ${webViewRequest.body}")
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, webViewRequest)
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This only works for XMLHttpRequest requests. Not for anything else.

Comment: It's supposed to work also for fetch calls as well as form submissions. Can you please file an issue on GitHub if you find a page where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution I found. It is an interesting hack. I have converted to work with Xamarin.Android so I am sure it will work for Native Android.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655940/4880012