# How to get post data on shouldInterceptRequest?

Tags: android, android-webview

On the Android `WebView`, since API 21, the `shouldInterceptRequest` method passes a `WebResourceRequest`. This is very useful for intercepting requests but I noticed that on `POST` requests, it doesn't pass any post data. Is there some way around this?

Edit: the question that was pointed to when marking this one as duplicate is very outdated, I'm specifically talking about the new `WebResourceRequest`.

Comment: Where is this about?

Comment: On the `shouldInterceptRequest` method.

Comment: The shouldInterceptRequest method of what?

Comment: Of the `WebView`.

Comment: You are not going to write a better post?

Comment: Sorry I guess I don't know how to better explain it. Anyone familiar with the `WebView` will know what I'm referring to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept POST requests in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954049/intercept-post-requests-in-a-webview)

Comment: That question is very outdated. Doesn't cover `WebResourceRequest`.