# Webview doesn't show a specific website

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to do a webview based application for [this website](https://demo.frappecloud.com/) to show it in a mobile application.

when I put any different site the application work great, but in this specific site never show the second page when I clicked in the button to go to the desk page.
 However, I put a Log statement in the `onPageFinished` method and log that the page is loaded completely.

My Code Here

```
final WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("WEBSITE", "Page Loaded.");

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("WEBSITE", url);
                myWebView.loadUrl(url);

                return false;
            }


        });

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://demo.frappecloud.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. If you check the documentation you will see that :

```
This method is not called for requests using the POST "method"
```

When you are submitting the Form, you are making a POST request, which is basically ignored.

Here is the link: [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))

Also check this reference where it says how you could load a URL with POST data: [LOAD A POST REQUEST INTO A WEBVIEW IN ANDROID](http://belencruz.com/2012/12/do-post-request-on-a-webview-in-android/)

Consider checking this thread: [Android - how to intercept a form POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3664440/891092)